# MSBuild "The windows SDK version 10.0.19041.0 was not found" even though it's installed

Tags: visual-studio, winapi, msbuild

I'm trying to build my Visual Studio solution with MSBuild and I'm using this command to do so:
`msbuild mysolution.sln /p:Configuration=Debug /p:PlatformToolset=v142`

But I get this following error:

> C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\MSBuild\Microsoft\VC\v160\Microsoft.Cpp.WindowsSDK.targets(46,5): error MSB8036: The Windows SDK version 10.0.19041.0 was not found. Install the required version of Windows SDK or change the SDK version in the project property pages or by right-clicking the solution and selecting "Retarget solution". [D:...\mysolution.vcxproj]

Even though I have it installed in Visual Studio Installer and Visual Studio can use it without an issue:

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using the `vcvarsall.bat` before the msbuild fixed it.

`"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Auxiliary\Build\vcvarsall.bat" x86 10.0.19041.0`

I think you might also need to do that before the msbuild:
`set UseEnv=true`

Comment: Great! Thanks for sharing your solution here, you could accept it as the answer, so it could help other community members who get the same issues and we could archive this thread, thanks.

Comment: Thanks for the reminder, I will accept it once it lets me in 2 days.