# Visual Studio 2022: MSB8036 since upgrading to VS2022

Tags: c++, visual-studio, msbuild, visual-studio-2022

I've been unable to build C++ projects since upgrading to VS2022. No matter what I do, it cannot programmatically find the Windows SDK files it needs, always claiming MSB8036 (the extremely generic "it can't find the Windows SDK" error).

To be absolutely clear, the version of the Windows SDK that it is looking for (10.0.19041.0) is the one that is installed. At various times, it has been installed using both the Visual Studio installer *and* the standalone installer (the latter of which apparently fixed this issue for some people). I had even tried installing an older SDK several times, which still failed, even when solutions were specifically retargeted.

**EDIT:** To be even more clear, I've also tried simple solutions like the one outlined [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68720886/19415750).

So far, I have tried:

- uninstalling and reinstalling (after a recent reinstall, the VS IDE won't load anymore, so I'm stuck with Build Tools)
- installing a different edition (Build Tools vs Community)
- running `sfc /scannow` (it found and fixed some errors, but none fixed the issue with MSBuild)
- removing the symlinks I had and allowing Visual Studio to install directly to my system drive (to be clear, the symlinks did not cause issues with VS2019, but I was unsure whether VS2022 had issues with them)
- running `InstallCleanup.exe -f`
- installing VS2019 again (despite working before, it won't anymore)
- checking the environment variables manually (everything points to where the files are located)
- checking the registry manually (couldn't find anything, not sure what I'd be looking for)

I was able to get it to pass the check for the Windows SDK by hardcoding the (x64) paths (which were literally the same) into the Microsoft.Cpp.WindowsSDK.targets file, but it would then fail to find windows.h at build time (this is also untenable for non-x64 targets).

I am out of ideas. Has anyone else had this issue? Are there any fixes that don't involve reinstalling Windows?

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2Ag4dGyScog, Just a random suggestion but he's talking about an issue which is something you haven't tried. OTOH he's talking about VS 2019

Comment: @john This is almost definitely what is wrong because SDKManifest.xml does not, in fact, exist. So thank you. However, I do not have access to the proper SDKManifest.xml file, so I don't know what the contents are supposed to be. Any chance you know where I can get that info?

Comment: The last time I ran into this kind of problem when upgrading MSVS IDE & compilers, I started a brand new project, copied all my source files into that project, and *voilà* problem solved.  Sure, it's the "abandon ship" and start over approach, but it got me past trying to find the proverbial one bad line in the project file that skunked the brew.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@john's comment [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72755784/visual-studio-2022-msb8036-since-upgrading-to-vs2022#comment128510216_72755784) provided the answer. I then was able to grab the proper SDKManifest.xml from [here](https://github.com/ojdkbuild/tools_toolchain_sdk10_19041/blob/master/SDKManifest.xml), which is basically the same as the version given in the video with the Windows SDK version swapped out.

Comment: Hi ,glad to know you've found the solution to resolve this issue! Please consider answering it and accepting it as an answer to change its status to Answered. See [can I answer my own question..](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer), Just a reminder :)