# SDK "Microsoft.UniversalCRT.Debug" is not found

Tags: c#, visual-studio, xaml, uwp

I faced SDK not finding the issue while making a "Blank App, Packaged with Windows Application Packaging Project (WinUI 3 in Desktop)" project in the visual studio 2022 community and using C# programming language.

This is the full error message: Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Source  Suppression State
Error   MSB3774 Could not find SDK "Microsoft.UniversalCRT.Debug, Version=10.0.22621.0".    App7 (Package)  C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\MSBuild\Current\Bin\amd64\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets   2623    Build

[And an image of the Error list](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OTMJh.png)

Please remember that I didn't change the code at all.

Thanks for your kind helps.

I tried to install the CRT Universal SDK from VS individual components but didn't work
[Image of individual components](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hlMWb.png)
also tried this solution which didn't work: [MSBuild "The windows SDK version 10.0.19041.0 was not found" even though it's installed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68720536/msbuild-the-windows-sdk-version-10-0-19041-0-was-not-found-even-though-its-in)

Comment: I am leave this to be here for others as well

Comment: I am installed Universal Windows platform development workload and that fixed my issue

Answer (score 1):

I had the same error, while running Visual Studio 2022 on a Windows 10 machine.
The problem disappeared after installing "Windows 11 SDK", at the same version of the specified "Microsoft.UniversalCRT.Debug" reported by the error (that is: 10.0.22621.0, in this case).

[image]

Comment: I encountered a similar problem, only with a different version in the error. Installing the SDK that matched the one reported as missing solved it. Thanks for the tip!